# How to send transactional email using Mailgun CURL PhP

Tags: php, email, curl, mailgun

Answered below, Sharing my knowledge for future developers

How do I send transactional email via Mailgun

I searched for solutions online, but did not find any solution online.

Feel free too add up your answers to help the community.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//mailgun send transactional manil
$from_who = "YOUR COMPANY NAME HERE <do-not-reply@YOUR_DOMAIN NAME.com>";
$to_who = "receiver@example.com";
$subject= "Test Subject";
$mail_content = "Just testing some mailgun awesomeness";
$data = array(
'from' => $from_who ,
'to' => $to_who ,
'subject' => $subject,
'text' => $mail_content,
);
$post = http_build_query($data);
$versw = curl_init("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mail.example.com/messages"); 
//the mail.example.com - THIS IS GOTTEN FROM YOUR MAILGUN DASHBOARD, it is the subdomain registered on Mailgun platform for sending emails
curl_setopt($versw, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($versw, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($versw, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:YOUR API KEY, ALSO GOTTEN ON MAILGUN DASHBOARD");
curl_setopt($versw, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($versw, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$run_curl = curl_exec($versw);
$run_clode = curl_close($versw);
//var_dump($run_curl);
$array_respo = json_decode($run_curl, true);
//var_dump($array_respo);
@$z_id = $array_respo["id"];
@$z_message = $array_respo["message"];
?>
```

Expected response in $z_id is your message id followed by your domain

Expected response in $z_message is Your message has been queued. Message sent!

Happy Coding.